# Web-response not returning actual webpage source

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Few days ago i was extracting webpage source from http://www.kse.com.pk/phps/mktSummary.php link successfully, now when i try to do the same it returns following response

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"><meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"><script type="text/javascript">function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { var exdate = new Date(); exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays); document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/"; } function getHostUri() { var loc = document.location; return loc.toString(); } setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 10); setCookie('DOAReferrer', document.referrer, 10); location.href = getHostUri();</script></head><body><noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript></body></html>
```

Above link is used as frame on this website: http://www.kse.com.pk
And I'm using this code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.kse.com.pk/phps/mktSummary.php");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
source = new StreamReader(resStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these lines in WebRequest solved my problem

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
request.Headers.Add("Cookie: YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;");
```

Replace `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with your ip address

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string webPage = "";
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    webPage = wc.DownloadString("http://www.kse.com.pk/phps/mktSummary.php");
}
```